# Groups whose automorphism tower is finitely generated

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group. Then the automorphism group $\text{Aut}(G)$ of $G$ need not be finitely generated.

However, there are classes of f.g. groups for which the automorphism group will always be f.g., such as polycyclic groups: it is a result by Auslander from 1969 that the automorphism group of a polycyclic group is even finitely *presented*.

Let $\text{Aut}^0(G) := G$, and for $n \geq 1$ let $\text{Aut}^n(G)$ be defined inductively as $\text{Aut}(\text{Aut}^{n-1}(G))$.

My question is: **what are some examples of groups $G$ such that $\text{Aut}^n(G)$ is f.g. for all $n \geq 0$?**

Now, while $\text{Aut}(G)$ is f.g. if $G$ is polycyclic by the above, the automorphism group of a polycyclic group need not be polycyclic, as far as I am aware, which would indicate that it is at least conceivable that $\text{Aut}^n(G)$ need not be f.g. for all $n \geq 1$ when $G$ is polycyclic. But I do not know of any counterexamples in this class.

Note that any finite group satisfies the question. Also, if $G$ is taken as $\mathbb{Z}$, then its automorphism group is $C_2$. Are there any infinite examples where every automorphism group is infinite f.g.?

Comment: $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Z)=C_2$ and from there the tower is made of finite groups.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I was just writing an edit to address this! Thanks.

Comment: The automorphism group of a free group of finite rank is finitely generated.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, of course you're right -- even finitely presented. I had in mind a Baumslag-Solitar group as a counterexample, and free groups of finite rank as an example. Somehow they got swapped around in my mind when writing this up...

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ is a complete group, that is, with trivial center and no outer automorphisms, then $$G\simeq \text{Aut}(G)$$
as every automorphism is the conjugation by some element, and the map $g\mapsto g\cdot g^{-1}$ has a trivial kernel.

For such a group, the tower is constant, so all you need is to find a finitely generated, infinite, complete group. You will find one in Victor S. Guba's *A finitely generated complete group*, 1987, DOI:10.1070/im1987v029n02abeh000969.

Comment: Guba's examples have properties much harder to obtain (uniquely divisible). A low-tech example of a complete group, in addition finitely presented, is $\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbf{Z})\ltimes\mathbf{Z}^d$ for $d\ge 3$.